# application rejected due to YouTube videos google console

Tags: android-studio, youtube, console-application, google-play-console, google-developers-console

I have uploaded the application in Google Console, but I received a message that the application was rejected, and they sent me this picture, there are YouTube videos in the application, but I do not understand the problem and do not know the solution, please help me.

[image]

Comment: Did they not explain the rejection? Just guessing, maybe they do not allow embedded YouTube content within an app. I mean, they’re YouTube for that.. post the rejection message..

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about Google's policy and is not a programming question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant show your own ads over or adjacent to a YouTube video in your app, only YouTube can monetize their videos.